# Clicking noise in audio when using “multi-output device” for video playback in OS X

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth, noise

I'm trying to watch a movie with my wife, and we are both using headphones — she is using Bluetooth, and mine are plugged into standard 3.5mm headphone jack.

I've created "multi-output device" in Audio MIDI Setup, added both headphones to the list of devices, so this setup outputs sound to both devices at once. Problem is that there is noise.

Whatever output is set as "Master device", it does not suffer from noise, but the other has frequent loud clicks (just like if audio frame is being ripped). Playing with sampling rates and drift correction didn't seem to fix this. I'm using OS X 10.9, and I've tried this on three different Macs, so it's definitely not a hardware issue.

So, is there any way to get rid of those clicks? Some lag is generally acceptable, as long as those annoying clicking noises are gone.

Comment: Sounds like the machine can't keep up - data on what machine, movie app etc might be useful

Comment: Machines are MBP 17" Late 2011 and two different MBPr 15" Early 2013s. Movie app does not matter — "secondary" audio device clicks when Firefox plays audio through HTML5 audio or flash player, in VLC, in iTunes, with videogames etc. Even builtin volume feedback sounds has this noise — but only on "secondary" device. When secondary device becomes master, it sounds clear, and now-secondary becomes clicky.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. Instead of using "multi output device" use "aggregate device". The setup is the same, just a different device.

Comment: An aggregate device is for multiple inputs, not multiple outputs. I have the same problem as you, can you describe how your aggregate device is set up?